# There are two types of apples. One's 120 gr and the other one is 200gr. I need to buy 1000 gr of apples. How many apples I can buy at most?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

There are two types of apples. One's 120 gr and the other one is 200gr. I need to buy 1000 gr of apples. How many apples I can buy at *most*?

I need the algebra on this one, I tried

$120x + 200y = 1000$ but don't know what to do from that point.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: In how many ways you can express $25$ using form : $3x+5y$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean pedja

Comment: divide equation by $40$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy 5 of the first type and 2 of the second type for a total of 7.  This is optimal since we can't buy any more than 5 of the first type and still end up with exactly a kilogram, and if we buy any fewer than 5 of the first type we will end up with fewer than 7 apples.  I'm sorry but I don't know a general way to solve this type of problem without enumerating all of the partitions.  The linear equation is correct but it needs to be solved in such a way that $x+y$ is maximized and also constrained to integers.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
120 a + 200 b = 1000 \\
3a + 5b = 25
$$
Now by extended Euclidean algorithm
$$
\underline{5}=\underline{3}\cdot 1+\underline{2} \\
\underline{3}=\underline{2}\cdot 1+\underline{1}
$$
Thus
$$
\underline{1}=\underline{3}-\underline{2}\cdot 1 = \underline{3}-\left(\underline{5}-\underline{3}\cdot 1\right) = \underline{3}-\underline{5}+\underline{3}=2\cdot\underline 3 - \underline 5
$$
And
$$
\underline{3}\cdot 50 +\underline{5}\cdot \left(-25\right) = 25
$$
Apparently adding $5t$ to the coefficient to $3$ and $-3t$ to the coefficient of $5$ preserves the right hand side
$$
\underline{3}\cdot \left(50+5t\right)+\underline{5}\cdot \left(-25+3t\right) = 25
$$
Because $a,b>0$ we find that the least $t$ would be $-9$
$$
\underline{3}\cdot\left(50-45\right) + \underline 5 \cdot \left(-25+27\right) = 25
$$
A bigger $t$ does not yield $a,b>0$ and a smaller $t$ yields a less $a+b$ (because it adds 3 and removes 5 from $a+b$)

Thus solution is $a=5, b=2$

Comment: Thanks - but way too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

To go off what peja mentioned, I think this is a relatively simple and intuitive way to see what's happened.

We start with $120x+200y=1000$. Now divide the equation by 40 - this leaves us with
$$3x + 5y = 25.$$

Some rearranging turns this into $$3x = 5(5-y).$$

Now, both $x$ and $y$ are meant to be nonnegative integers, which also means both sides of this equation are. This gives two possibilities: either both sides are zero, in which case $x=0$ and $y=5$ (i.e., you buy 5 apples weighing 200g). Or they're both nonzero, in which case they have to have the same prime factors - everything that divides the right hand side divides the left hand side and vice versa.

So because 3 is a factor of the left hand side and $5$ isn't divisible by $3$, $5-y$ has to be divisible by 3. The only way for that to be true without ending up needing to buy negative apples of one or the other kind is for $y=2$. Then $3x=15$ and so $x=5$. This gives you seven apples in total, more than the zero case, so that's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that we will not be buying many apples. For "large" problems, we would need general theory, or a suitable computer program.  But this is a small problem, and algebra need not come into play.

You will be buying at most $5$ big apples.

Try buying $0$ big apples, and the rest small. It is easy to see that we can't get to exactly $1000$ using small apples, since $120$ does not divide $1000$ exactly.

Try buying $1$ big apple, and the rest small. Then we need to get to $800$ grams using only small apples. Can't be done, since $120$ is not a factor of $1000$.

Try buying $2$ big apples, and the rest small. That leaves $600$ grams to be made with small apples. This *can* be done, since $\frac{600}{120}=5$.

Try buying $3$ big apples, the rest small. Can't be done. Try buying $4$. Can't be done.

Try buying $5$ big apples. Works fine.

With $2$ big, we had a total of $7$ apples, with $5$ big we had a total of $5$ apples. So we get the largest number of apples by buying $2$ big, $5$ small, a total of $7$.

It might have been easier to see what's going on by knocking off a $0$, and using $12$, $20$, $100$.  It might have been still easier to further divide by $4$, and using $3$, $5$, $25$.

**Remark:** Note that there are no $x$'s and/or $y$'s in the analysis.

For me, writing $120x+200y=1000$, and then perhaps $3x+4y=25$, would be automatic. But the rest would have been exactly like in the above solution: a scan of the possibilities, leading to a quick answer.  The equation would only be used as an organizing device, easier (for me) than visualizing small yellow apples and big red apples. Remember that this is a *concrete* problem. Symbols can be very useful, but it is even more useful to experiment, in order to find out what's *really* going on.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Peđa, the requirement of buying $1000\, \mathrm{g}$ total translates into
$$
120x+200y = 1000 \overset{\color{blue}{1/40}}{\implies} 3x + 5y = 25
$$
where $x$ is the number of smaller apples, and $y$ the bigger ones. Since $\gcd(3,5)=1$ divides $25$, [the equation has integer solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation). Moreover, since $(x,y) =(0,5)$ is a particular solution, the full family of integer solutions is
$$
x = 5n \quad \text{and} \quad y = 5-3n, \quad \text{for}  \  n\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Now, since we can't buy a negative amount of apples, we require $x,y >0$. For $x=5n\ge 0$ we get $n \ge 0$, and for $y = 5-3n \ge 0$ we get $ n\le \frac{5}{3}<2$. The only integers $n$ that satisfy $0 \le n <2$ are $n=0,1$. This means there's only *two* possible ways of buying the apples to get a kilogram total in general, so the one out of these two with more apples is the optimal way. Plugging in $n=0,1$ into $x=5n$ and $y = 5-3n$ gives $(x,y) = (0,5)$ and $(x,y) = (5,2)$. So the total number of apples in one case is $x+y = 0+5 =5$ and in the other it's $x+y =5+2= 7$. So $7$ is the maximal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is the number of smaller apples (of weight $120$ g) and $y$ the number of bigger apples (of weight $200$ g) we thus want to maximize $ f(x,y)= x+y$ subject to the constaint $120 x + 200 y = 1000$, which is equivalent to the constraint $y = \frac15\left(25 - 3x\right)$.  Subsituting this expression for $y$ into $f(x,y) =x+y$ we want to thus find the maximum of
$$
f(x) = x + \frac15\left(25 - 3x\right) = \frac25 x+ 5
$$
subject to $x \ge 0$ and $ y= \frac15\left(25 - 3x\right) \ge 0$, which implies that $0\le x \le \frac{25}{3}$. Since $f(x)$ is increasing, we just need to find the biggest integer between $0$ and $ \frac{25}{3}<9$ such that $y = \frac15\left( 25-3x\right) = 5- \frac{3x}{5}$ is also an integer. Out of the $9$ possibilties for $x\in \{0,1,2,\dots,7,8 \}$, only $x=0$ and $x=5$ make $y = 5- \frac{3x}{5}$ and integer as well. Since out of these two possibilities the biggest $x$ is $x=5$, this is the optimal solution, resulting in
$$
x+y\big\vert_{x=5} = x+\left(5- \frac{3x}{5} \right)\Bigg\vert_{x=5}  =5 +5 -3 = 7
$$
as the maximum number of apples.